# Prevent frequent compilation in Homebrew

Tags: linux, macos, homebrew, compile

`homebrew doctor` warns me to keep an updated homebrew database and packages, telling me this:

> You haven't updated for at least 24 hours, this is a long time in brewland!

However, when I try to update my packages by `brew update` then `brew upgrade`, homebrew starts compiling, instead of installing precompiled packages (called bottles), some packages that I would never try to compile myself, such as `gcc`, `macvim`, `octave`. I can accept doing it only once for initial installation if necessary, but for every update, compiling gcc (and others) every week is not sane for a MacBook Air user.

Is there any switch to tell homebrew to *NOT* install packages that requires compiling unless necessary by dependency, or manually stated to do so? I could not find such a switch by searching through the internet (or in the official documentation), and I prefer not to pin every single package which requires finding out which packages need compiling, then remembering to update those pinned packages from time to time, which should be a package manager's job.

Comment: Apparently, you need Homebrew Cask to install binaries.

Comment: I am using homebrew cask. Should I do some configuration so that binaries have higher priorities?

Comment: As I understand it, the compilation happens because it is needed. I assume the binaries aren't available at the time you are do installation. It's not like it is installing everything just to install it, it's installing things that have been updated. The updated binaries may not have made it into the repositories before you do an update.